# How does rspec-rails detects folders?

Tags: rspec2, rspec-rails

For example if I have ./views/*_spec then I can use render function. But what if I want to use render function from my ./integrations/*_spec ? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to include module from RSpec into describe block

```
include RSpec::Rails::ViewExampleGroup
```